# Hibernate + Spring Boot: any way to use a jointable as an entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, join

Let's say I have tables PERSON and COMPANY, connected by the table PERSON_COMPANY in which aside from the foreign keys I also store information about update_date, create_date and status of the connection:

[image: DB simple diagram image]

This is how I've realized the connection in Person class, which works well:

```java
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "person_contact",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "person_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "company_id"))
    private List<Company> companyList;
```

The problem comes when I try to create an entity for PERSON_COMPANY table as there is information that I will need in some cases:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="person_company")
public class PersonCompany {
   ...
}
```

I get an **SchemaManagementException: Export identifier [person_company] encountered more than once.**

Is there a way to use a join table as an entity as well?

*I'm using springboot and hibernate with mariaDB.*

Comment: If not possible offer an alternative solution instead

Comment: Your collection now needs to be a collection of `PersonCompany` with a `OneToMany` on both the `Person` and `Company`. As you now want to use that instead of linking directly to `Company`.